# Does $R$ contain a subring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Consider the ring
> $$R=\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}a&b\\0&c\end{matrix}\right):a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$$
>
> with respect to ordainary addition and multiplication of matricies.
>
> Does $R$ contain a subring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

How would I find this?

Comment: How about $\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$, $a\in\mathbb Z$?

Comment: There are three integer parameters. The most natural is to fix two to zero and see if what you get is a subring.

Comment: Hint: A subring isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$ is necessarily contained in the center. Have you identified the center of $R$? Certain matrices commute with all matrices (of a compatible type).

Comment: @amsmath That's not a subring unless you live in the (IMO strange) part of the world, where a subring of $R$ need not contain $1_R$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Judging from the question that is asked, it is highly unlikely that the OP knows this, or even what *center* means.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen amsmath did not say that it was. It is good to leave something for the OP to do.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier But your suggestion does not produce subrings at all? See my comment to amsmath.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen No but it makes you think (which for the moment we have no proof that the OP did), and once you've seen why these options fail, the right one is obvious.

Comment: Ok, forget about the center. Any subring of $R$ contains $1_R$. Hence it also contains $1_R+1_R$ and $1_R+1_R+1_R$. Where does that lead you?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Fair enough. I'm not an algebra guy. But I can see the subring now. ;-)

Comment: Yet @amsmath's approach was more pedagogic imho. You don't give straight answers to HW questions.

Comment: @James You haven't answered amsmath's excellent question.

Comment: No $\left(\begin{matrix}a&0\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)$ is not a subring as it does not contain the multiplication identity element.

Comment: @James $R$ is obviously not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$. It should be "1-dimensional".

Comment: @James Right, and so it is also wrong to only choose the right lower corner. But can you somehow combine those two?

Comment: So $\left(\begin{matrix}a&0\\0&c\end{matrix}\right)$ will be a subring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @James:  you’re getting closer; think about what you would map $a\in\Bbb     Z$ to?

Comment: I would map it to $1$?

Comment: You would map the multiplicative identity in $\mathbb Z$ to that in $R$